# Как в БД MySql хранить видео файлы?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Здравствуйте. Создаю проект по Java и естественно, как любой новичок, зашёл в тупик... Сайт для онлайн просмотра сериалов. Как в БД MySql загружать и как хранить видео-файлы? А самое главное, какой запрос в коде корректно эти видео отобразит? Спасибо

Comment: Их не нужно хранить в БД, их нужно хранить на диске. В БД нужно хранить относительные пути к ним.

Comment: только что это понял. подскажите, пожалуйста, как корректно прописать путь?

Comment: Задам вопрос от обратного - а в чем пробема с путем?

Comment: проблема во мне) я это делаю первый раз

Comment: Видеофайл загружается в файловую систему. Скрипт сервера, выполняющий приём файла от клиента и сохранение его на сервере, точно знает, куда и с каким именем он поместил файл, а также должен знать, как из этого пути сформировать ссылку для клиента для загрузки или онлайн-просмотра этого файла. Вот, выполнив загрузку файла, он и должен такой путь поместить в таблицу.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO GAME values (3, 'NameVideo',LOAD_FILE("C:\\Users\\Public\\Videos\\Sample Video\\test.mpg"));
```

Comment: премного благодарен

Comment: Поскольку планируется ОНЛАЙН-просмотр, настоятельно советую отказаться от хранения файла в BLOB. Ведь для онлайн-просмотра серверу всё равно придётся выполнить извлечение файла из БД в файловую систему - ни один плеер не умеет принять видеопоток непосредственно из поля таблицы БД. Даже если с самого начала - а ведь клиент может затребовать просмотр и с произвольной точки...

Comment: Благодарю за отличное разъяснение. Скажите, если я в таком случае в БД положу только само имя файла, то где лучше хранить видео? На хосте? Извините, я совсем зелёный в этих вопросах